# Why is the Debye Hückel Limiting Law called the "limiting law"?

Tags: physical-chemistry

I could not find any source which explains this point well.

I looked up Atkin's physical chemistry and Castellan's physical chemistry book but could not quite understand the logic bhind it being called the limiting law.

Comment: It is only valid in the limit of low concentration. You see significant deviations from it at higher concentrations

Comment: For a 1:1 electrolyte, a  limit of $10^{-3} \pu{mol dm^{-3}}$ is typically put on the concentration. There are similar equations that can be used at higher concentrations but involve parameters that have to be fitted to the data.

Answer (score 2):

The Huckel limiting law allows us to determine the activity coefficient of an ion in a dilute solution of a known ionic strength.

Here's an ***appealing*** answer which makes perfect sense to me that I found on [EveryScience](http://www.everyscience.com/Chemistry/Physical/Electrochemistry/b.1150.php)

> **The name 'limiting law' is applied because in the limit of arbitrarily low molalities (ie as the concentration of the solute gets
>   closer and closer to zero), all solutions are expected to behave in a
>   manner consistent with the expression.**